# Why doesn't my matcherFunction work? (Angular 11)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I want to achieve the following routing with matcherFunction.

```
{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('@feature/modules/trade.module').then(
        (module) => module.TradeModule
      ),
  },
  {
    path: 'new',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('@feature/modules/trade.module').then(
        (module) => module.TradeModule
      ),
  },
```

This is my matcherFunction and it works for `new` path but it doesn't work for the empty path.

```
export function matcherFunction(url: UrlSegment[]) {
  if (url.length == 1) {
    const path = url[0].path;
    if (path === '' || path.startsWith('new')) {
      return { consumed: url };
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If I remember correctly the empty path doesn't create a `UrlSegment`, so in that case you need to check against `url.length === 0`

Comment: Okay so what should it return in that case?

Comment: the same `return { consumed: url };`